# Search for a value in a string and if the value exists, print it all by itself in a new column

Tags: r, regex

The question I would like to answer is this: "Are the word LIVER or HEART present in x? If so, then print that value in a corresponding row. If not print an NA." I have accomplished this using `ifelse()` and `grepl()`. However, I was wondering if there is a better way to search for a value in a string and if the value exists, print it all by itself in a new column. Can anyone recommend a good approach?

```
x <- c("LIVER 1","HEART COMP 1","CARCASS COMP 1")

y <- ifelse(grepl("LIVER", x), "LIVER", 
       ifelse(grepl("HEART",x), "HEART","NA"))

> data.frame(x,y)

               x     y
1        LIVER 1 LIVER
2   HEART COMP 1 HEART
3 CARCASS COMP 1    NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `stringr` package which provides a nice regex API:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("LIVER 1","HEART COMP 1","CARCASS COMP 1")
y = str_extract(x, "LIVER|HEART")
data.frame(x,y)
# Note that this a true NA value, not a string "NA" as in your question
               x     y
1        LIVER 1 LIVER
2   HEART COMP 1 HEART
3 CARCASS COMP 1  <NA>
```