# Pandas str.contains - Search for multiple values in a string and print the values in a new column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I just started coding in Python and want to build a solution where you would search a string to see if it contains a given set of values.

I've find a similar solution in R which uses the stringr library: [Search for a value in a string and if the value exists, print it all by itself in a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707348/search-for-a-value-in-a-string-and-if-the-value-exists-print-it-all-by-itself-i)

The following code seems to work but i also want to output the three values that i'm looking for and this solution will only output one value:

```
#Inserting new column
df.insert(5, "New_Column", np.nan)

#Searching old column
df['New_Column'] = np.where(df['Column_with_text'].str.contains('value1|value2|value3', case=False, na=False), 'value', 'NaN')
```

------ Edit ------

So i realised i didn't give that good of an explanation, sorry about that.

Below is an example where i match fruit names in a string and depending on if it finds any matches in the string it will print out either true or false in a new column. Here's my question: Instead of printing out true or false i want to print out the name it found in the string eg. apples, oranges etc.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text = [('I want to buy some apples.', 0),
         ('Oranges are good for the health.', 0),
         ('John is eating some grapes.', 0),
         ('This line does not contain any fruit names.', 0),
         ('I bought 2 blueberries yesterday.', 0)]
labels = ['Text','Random Column']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(text, columns=labels)

df.insert(2, "MatchedValues", np.nan)

foods =['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'blueberries']

pattern = '|'.join(foods)

df['MatchedValues'] = df['Text'].str.contains(pattern, case=False)

print(df)
```

Result

```
                                          Text  Random Column  MatchedValues
0                   I want to buy some apples.              0           True
1             Oranges are good for the health.              0           True
2                  John is eating some grapes.              0           True
3  This line does not contain any fruit names.              0          False
4            I bought 2 blueberries yesterday.              0           True
```

Wanted result

```
                                          Text  Random Column  MatchedValues
0                   I want to buy some apples.              0           apples
1             Oranges are good for the health.              0           oranges
2                  John is eating some grapes.              0           grapes
3  This line does not contain any fruit names.              0          NaN
4            I bought 2 blueberries yesterday.              0           blueberries
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
foods =['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'blueberries']

def matcher(x):
    for i in foods:
        if i.lower() in x.lower():
            return i
    else:
        return np.nan

df['Match'] = df['Text'].apply(matcher)

#                                           Text        Match
# 0                   I want to buy some apples.       apples
# 1             Oranges are good for the health.      oranges
# 2                  John is eating some grapes.       grapes
# 3  This line does not contain any fruit names.          NaN
# 4            I bought 2 blueberries yesterday.  blueberries
```

Answer (score 23):

You need to set the regex flag (to interpret your search as a regular expression):

```
whatIwant = df['Column_with_text'].str.contains('value1|value2|value3',
                                                 case=False, regex=True)

df['New_Column'] = np.where(whatIwant, df['Column_with_text'])
```

------ Edit ------

Based on the updated problem statement, here is an updated answer:

You need to define a capture group in the regular expression using parentheses and use the `extract()` function to return the values found within the capture group.  The `lower()` function deals with any upper case letters

```
df['MatchedValues'] = df['Text'].str.lower().str.extract( '('+pattern+')', expand=False)
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: No, but i have edited my post now to make it more clear on what i'm aiming to do. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just wondering, did you try my updated (one line) solution?